# React js - рендеринг тормозит

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня есть 2 компонента
Первый это таблица на основе fixed-data-table-2,(около 100 строк, будет больше) при клике на ячейку таблицы хочу показать модальное окно. В браузере вижу предупреждение **[Violation] 'click' handler took 204ms**, при том что я ещё даже не рендерил модалку просто изменил состояние в родительском компоненте.

Я думаю что это связано с тем что таблица перерисовывается после смены состояния, но почему так долго? Разве react не должен делать diff и отрисовывать только то-что поменялось? Поправьте если не прав.

Как можно избавиться от этого, может быть как-то по другому организовать взаимодействие компонентов? Спасибо

Comment: если вы используете редакс из коробки и изменили состояние сторы. то да, перерисовывется всё дерево. так как редакс иммутабелен и в реакт компонент прилетает новая ссылка на объект...

Comment: Выложите пример кода, так на словах трудно помочь